# Affinity Masking

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, numa

One of the servers I'm responsible for now was set up under the wrong license so can only use 40 cores on the server.  This has led to an imbalance in the NUMA node schedulers.  I'm planning on using `ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION` to fix this, I'm wondering if this is the correct way of doing it and what the potential risks are of running this?  From what I've been able to find I don't believe a restart is required, is that correct?  Unfortunately I don't have a server I could test this on.

```
ALTER SERVER CONFIGURATION
SET PROCESS AFFINITY CPU = 1 TO 10, 17 TO 26, 33 TO 42, 49 TO 58;
```

**Version**:

> SQL Server 2012 Enterprise
>       4 sockets with 8 cores, 16 logical processors (Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-4640 0 @ 2.40GHz)

This is not a VM,

Comment: To get an accurate answer, can you include the underlying physical server's information, like # of sockets, # of cores, CPU make/model, is hyperthreading on, is virtualization involved, etc?

Comment: If the wrong media was used for the install, and you are actually using EE Core licenses to cover the server, then you can simply perform an in-place Edition Upgrade using the SQL Server 2012 Enterprise Core Edition media.

Comment: I tried going the route of upgrading to the Core Edition but for some reason they don't want to at this time.  The databases on this server will be moving to a new VM within the next six months.  I'm hoping this will help the instance out until then.

Comment: Alternately, you may just want to license the server correctly because, with a physical server, you still have to license all cores present, affinity or no. Per Microsoft SQL Server Data Sheet  "To license a physical server—when running SQL Server in a physical OSE—all physical cores on the server must be licensed."

Comment: As far as I know, licensing terms count the number of cores. Disabling cores via affinity (or boot parameters) does not have an effect to licensing needs, as the cores still exist. Anyway, you should get a statement from your MS license vendor to be sure. Running improperly licensed setup for 6 months sounds risky.